# How to handle ALL requests (regardless endpoint) in firebase functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to handle errors in firebase functions. For instance if the route/function does not exist to throw error/send error back to client with some meaningful message. This is first time i am using firebase functions and i can't find solution in their docs or anywhere else.

what i do have now:

```
//...
// HTTP endpoints
exports.authorize = user.authorize;
exports.deleteUser = user.deleteUser;
```

What i need is to somehow handle case where someone access function which does not exist or send invalid headers. I want to handle this globally without need to wrap all functions into something.

Any help/tips appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Functions only respond to the endpoint URL they were assigned at the time of deployment, which matches the name they were given for export.  There are not wildcard or catch-all URLs.

What you can do instead is use [Firebase Hosting](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting) has a [forwarding proxy](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#rewrite-functions) and [rewrite](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#rewrites) any URLs using a wildcard to Firebase Hosting [to a specific named function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#rewrite-functions) that can handle the request.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This definetly would help (be correct answer) me if i would have firebase hosting. Sadly specification of this project limits me to use just firebase DB and cloud functions. So i can not use hosting to "proxy" request to some error handling function

Comment: If i would rewite functions to use "express" (so transform it to REST) and there handled the errors it may work

Comment: Cloud Functions simply does not support wildcard URLs that match any path on the allocated hostname for your project.  You can only handle a path that's the same as the name of the function.  If you need wildcards, Cloud Functions is not the right product for you.  Consider Cloud Run instead, so you can deploy a full express app that can handle anything under the root path "/".